# AfxGetApp() pointer getting destroyed

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am using ATL dll.

I have a CWinApp derived object. In its initInstance(), when I call AfxGetApp(), it works fine and gives me the pointer of CWinApp. But after some more function calls, when I call AfxGetApp()/AfxGetAppName() etc,in a different function, then it is returning NULL.

I guess that the CWinApp object is getting destroyed or something.  With that thought, I put a breakpoint in ExitInstance but the code is not reaching there either.

Could anyone help me out as to why this is happening and how can make it return the previous valid value.

Thanks

Comment: Any chance of a minimal code sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: `I am using ATL`.  Use MFC instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your DLL/EXE projects link to the same MFC library. I.e. Multibyte/unicode character set...